# SpringData Mongo projection ignore and overide the values on save

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Let me explain my problem with SpringData mongo, I have the following interface declared, I declared a custom query, with a projection to ignore the index, this example is only for illustration, in real life I will ignore a bunch of fields.

```
public interface MyDomainRepo extends MongoRepository<MyDomain, String> {
    @Query(fields="{ index: 0 }")
    MyDomain findByCode(String code);
}
```

In my MongoDB instance, the MyDomain has the following info, `MyDomain(code="mycode", info=null, index=19)`, so when I use the `findByCode` from MyDomainRepo I got the following info `MyDomain(code="mycode", info=null, index=null)`, so far so good, because this is expected behaviour, but the problem happens when..., I decided to save the `findByCode` return.

For instance, in the following example, I got the `findByCode` return and set the `info` property to `myinfo` and I got the object bellow.

```
MyDomain(code="mycode", info="myinfo", index=null)
```

So I used the `save` from MyDomainRepo, the index was ignored as expected by the projection, but, when I save it back, with or without an update, the SpringData Mongo, overridden the `index` property to null, and consequently, my record on the MongoDB instance is overridden too, the following example it's my MongoDB JSON.

```
{
    "_id": "5f061f9011b7cb497d4d2708",
    "info": "myinfo",
    "_class": "io.springmongo.models.MyDomain"
}
```

There's a way to tell to SpringData Mongo, to simply ignores the null fields on saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Save is a replace operation and you won't be able to signal it to patch some fields. It will replace the document with whatever you send
- Your option is to use the extension provided by Spring Data Repository to define custom repository methods

```
    public interface MyDomainRepositoryCustom {
 
      void updateNonNull(MyDomain myDomain);
 
    }
```

```
   public class MyDomainRepositoryImpl implements MyDomainRepositoryCustom {
 
     private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
 
     @Autowired
     public BookRepositoryImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
     }
 
     @Override
     public void updateNonNull(MyDomain myDomain) {
        //Populate the fileds you want to patch
        Update update = Update.update("key1", "value1")
                              .update("key2", "value2");

        // you can you Update.fromDocument(Document object, String... exclude) to
        // create you document as well but then you need to make use of `MongoConverter`  
        //to convert your domain to document. 

        // create `queryToMatchId` to mtach the id
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(queryToMatchId, update, MyDomain.class);
     }
 
    }
```

```
    public interface MyDomainRepository extends MongoRepository<..., ...>, 
                                            MyDomainRepositoryCustom {
    }
```